# How to simulate paralle requests in locust

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I am working with locust and new to it.
I have a scenario where on clicking a button on a website 3 requests are getting triggered. and all 3 of them are being hit parallelly. How can we simulate this in locust.
If I create three get/post request then the response time for the transaction would be the sum of all three requests which is not right.

As we have web_concurrent_start in Load runner and parallel controller in Jmeter, Do we have a similar method or way in locust?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example here: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/increase-performance.html#concurrency

```
def concurrent_request(url):
    self.client.get(url)

pool = gevent.pool.Pool()
urls = ["/url1", "/url2", "/url3"]
for url in urls:
    pool.spawn(concurrent_request, url)
pool.join()
```

this wont give you the response time as a sum, but you can fire a custom event for that. Use the XmlHttpUser in the docs as an example:

```
        request_meta = {
            "request_type": "xmlrpc",
            "name": name,
            "start_time": time.time(),
            "response_length": 0,
            "response": None,
            "context": {},
            "exception": None,
        }
        start_perf_counter = time.perf_counter()
        try:
            request_meta["response"] = func(*args, **kwargs) # this is where you do your concurrent requests!
        except Fault as e:
            request_meta["exception"] = e
        request_meta["response_time"] = (time.perf_counter() - start_perf_counter) * 1000
        self._request_event.fire(**request_meta)
```